# Dynamically add Fragments in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, materialdrawer

I was using `NavigationDrawer` from `android.support:design` library, and it worked fine, but now i have swithed to [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) by mikepenz, due to it's obvious features. But now i am stuck.

I want to add `Fragment` dynamically like i did with `android.support:design` library, in `android.support:design` library, i used `SharedPreferences`, to add/remove `Fragments` from settings like this:

```
mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
       mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
       if (savedPreferences.getBoolean("add_frag", true)) {
             if (menuItem.getTitle() == "frag") {
             FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
             xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new fragFragment()).commit();
       }
    }
}
```

Now how can i do the same with `MaterialDrawer`?

There are many ways to change fragment by `switch` statement or using something like this:

```
if (position == 0) {                      
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new fragFragment()).commit();
}
```

But these statement, doesn't help in adding fragment using `SharedPreferences`. If i try `SharedPreferences` on above statement `Fragment` won't change, and this quite obvious.

Please HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks very similar to the one you have currently.

First you build your drawer, and add some items, and add a listener. This listener allow you to execute whatever function you need:

```
//Create the drawer
new DrawerBuilder()
    .withActivity(this)
    .withToolbar(toolbar)
    .withAccountHeader(headerResult) //set the AccountHeader we created earlier for the header
    .addDrawerItems(
            new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Item 1").withIdentifier(1),
            new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Item 2").withIdentifier(2)
    )
    .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
            if (drawerItem != null) {
                if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 1) {
                    //do what you want to do for the first item
                } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 2) {
                    //do whatever you want to do for the second item
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    })
    .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
    .build();
```

---

There may be some other confusion on your side. `SharedPreference`s store data in your application. This has not really much to do with the `MaterialDrawer` in general, nor with `Fragment`s

Comment: Basically i am using SharedPreferences to populate navigation drawer.